# Handling page refresh in react with react-select

Tags: reactjs, setstate, react-select, async.js

I am very new to using React. I am using react-select for giving a drop down menu and trying to set the options for the drop down menu dynamically. Here is what I am doing:-

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.printlist = this.printlist.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            checked: false,
            values: [],
            mylist: [],
            myoptions:[]
        };
    }

     componentDidMount() {
            console.log("inside component did mount")
         
    
            var configservice = new AWS.ConfigService(); 
            var params = {
                ConfigurationAggregatorNames: [
                    'Proserve'
                ]
            };
    
    // I make a AWS config call to get the items for myoptions list as follows
    
    
        configservice.describeConfigurationAggregators(params, function(err, data) {
                    if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                    else {
                        console.log("accounts in config call: ", data.ConfigurationAggregators[0].AccountAggregationSources[0].AccountIds);
        
                        accounts = data.ConfigurationAggregators[0].AccountAggregationSources[0].AccountIds
                        console.log("accounts are: ", accounts)
                        var a;
                        for (a = 0; a < accounts.length; a++) { 
                            console.log("inside for loop")
                            var oj = { label: "", value: 0 }
                            oj.label = (accounts[a])
                            oj.value = accounts[a]
                            options.push(oj) //construct an array of objects
                        }
        
                       console.log("options are: ", options)
        
                    } // successful response
                });
        
                this.setState({myoptions:options})
                console.log("myoptions are: ",this.state.myoptions)
        
        
        
            }
```

The issue that I am facing is sometimes when I refresh the web page and try to select from my drop down, the options are coming as "No options"/none. I think since the config call that I am making inside my componentDidMount function is async, this is causing issues when the results are taking time to load. I added some console.log statements but as per observation, if I refresh the page and try to select the options from the drop down immediately, it shows None. But I see that my for loop gets executed and **options do have items.** But console.log statement for **"myoptions" does not print.** Attaching the screenshot for the reference. Any suggestions to handle this is much appreciated. [image: Browser dev console and drop down menu]

Comment: while fetching data in mount phase, display an spinner/loader. once the data is available conditionally render the select component.

Comment: This was really helpful, thanks a lot.